# To make a video of what I write in a tablet and what I speak

Tags: tablet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best software for desktop recording?](https://superuser.com/questions/6801/what-is-the-best-software-for-desktop-recording)

I am a teacher and use a tablet notebook as an alternative blackboard. It has worked for me very well, but I was wondering if there is anyway to make a video of what I write in the tablet in sync of what I speak. This will automatically create a video for lectures.

Can I do it?

FYI, my machine is Lenovo Thinkpad X201.   Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I know [Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/) has a gaming orientation, but it may be able to serve your purpose, assuming your tablet is a Windows machine.